# Htaccess File with Question Marks and Equals 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect from the following URL concepts into a 301 redirect URL but keep failing (doesnt seem to be working).

```
/blahblah?area=something
```

to

```
www.newdomain.com/blahblah/
```

I have tried the following but it did not working

```
Redirect 301 /blahblah.php/\?area=something www.newdomain.com/blahblah/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blahblah\.php/\?area=something [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /blahblah/$ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Not working, not even throwing back any URLS. I am going out to an external website as a rewrite rule, would that matter?

Comment: Can you clarify `I am going out to an external website as a rewrite rule` part?